# Flood-fill algorithm in Javascript not filling the entire grid when using for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion, flood-fill

I've been working at this all day, and I can't work out why this algorithm doesn't cover the entire grid when starting at position grid[1][1].

I start by setting up the grid and calculating the number of rows and columns in the grid to give me a limit on the edges of the array.

I then call the function, setting position grid[1][1] = 1, calculating the offset and making sure it is not outside the array and making sure the new position has not already been called before calling the function recursively.

I just can't figure out why this isn't working!

```
var grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];
var cols = grid.length;
var rows = grid[0].length;

floodFill(1, 1)

function floodFill(col, row) {
  grid[col][row] = 1;
  for (c_off = -1; c_off < 2; c_off++) {
    for (r_off = -1; r_off < 2; r_off++) {
      var i = col + c_off;
      var j = row + r_off;
      if (i > -1 && i < cols && j > -1 && j < rows) {
        if (grid[i][j] != 1) {
          floodFill(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

grid;

/*
output:
[ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ],
  [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]

expected output:
[ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ] 
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `c_off` and `r_off` are not defined as local variables (via the `var` or `let` keywords) so they are treated like a global variables which means that a recursive invocation of `floodFill()` overwrites the values for its calling invocation thereby interfering with the caller's iteration order.

The fix is simple: just add a `var` keyword in both for loops:

```
    function floodFill(col, row) {
        grid[col][row] = 1;
        for (var c_off = -1; c_off < 2; c_off++) {
            for (var r_off = -1; r_off < 2; r_off++) {
            var i = col + c_off;
            var j = row + r_off;
            if (i > -1 && i < cols && j > -1 && j < rows) {
                    if (grid[i][j] != 1) {
                        floodFill(i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Appendix**

You can move the detection of out-of-grid condition, and the check whether the given point is already filled, to the beginning of the function (instead of doing it just before the recursive call). Some may argue that the resulting code is simpler to understand:

```
    function floodFill(col, row) {
        if (col < 0 || col >= cols || row < 0 || row >= rows) {
            return;
        }

        if (grid[col][row] == 1) {
            return;
        }
        grid[col][row] = 1;
        for (var c_off = -1; c_off < 2; c_off++) {
            for (var r_off = -1; r_off < 2; r_off++) {
                floodFill(col + c_off, row + r_off);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I didn't realize that you had to set local variables in a recursive function!

Comment: @CharlieBrinleyCodd: you may want to take a look at the appendix I added.

Comment: I can see how that would be easier to read, would it also be less computationally intensive?

Comment: @CharlieBrinleyCodd - no.

Answer (score 0):

I think Itay Maman answer is probably better. I solved it this way. by changing `c_off < 5` and `r_off < 5`

```
var grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];
var cols = grid.length;
var rows = grid[0].length;
floodFill(1, 1)

function floodFill(col, row) {

   grid[col][row] = 1;

  for (c_off = -1; c_off < 5; c_off++) {
    for (r_off = -1; r_off < 5; r_off++) {
      var i = col + c_off;
      var j = row + r_off;
      if (i > -1 && i < cols && j > -1 && j < rows) {
        if (grid[i][j] != 1) {
          floodFill(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(grid);
```